# Flutter how to receive location intent

Tags: flutter, android-intent

I know how to receive basic intents like text or images with the [receive_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent) plugin. But now I also want to start my app if the user shares/receives some coordinates from another app f.e. google maps to open up this coordinates in the map of my application.

Does somebody of you have done this already? Is there a plugin I can use?
Thanks in advance.